# How to add json file to User in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Please help me.

I am creating an IOS app using Swift and Firebase.

I have a JSON file with email and password. Can I import this JSON file to the Users in Authentication. So that I can validate email and password.

[Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lLta.png)

Json File:

```
> [
 {
   "email": "haritha@gmail.com",
   "password": "Password"
 },
 {
   "email": "sravani@gmail.com",
   "password": "Password"
 },
 {
   "email": "sandeep@gmail.com",
   "password": "Password"
 },
 {
   "email": "padma@gmail.com",
   "password": "Password"
 },
 {
   "email": "syamu@gmail.com",
   "password": "Password"
 },
 {
   "email": "lakshmi@gmail.com",
   "password": "Password"
 }
]
```

Comment: I hope these passwords are encrypted...

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) for writing programs that manage users in Firebase Authentication.  This applies to all mobile platforms supported by Firebase, not just iOS/swift.

Comment: Hi this does not answer my question.   I have a JSON file with email and password. Can I import this JSON file to the Users in Authentication. So that I can validate email and password

Comment: Write the code yourself - read the JSON, parse it, iterate the entires, and use the admin SDK to create the users.

Comment: Is there any stackoverflow link on how to do this? or any example/article?

Comment: The documentation on how to manage users with the admin SDK is pretty straightforward.  If there is a specific problem with it, that sounds like either a bug request, or another SO question.